# Misapplication of the second isomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

Consider the ring $\Bbb{Q}[\varepsilon]:=\Bbb{Q}[X]/(X^2)$ and its natural subrings $\Bbb{Z}[\varepsilon]$ and $\Bbb{Q}$ as abelian groups. Then by the second isomorphism theorem
$$\Bbb{Z}[\varepsilon]/(\Bbb{Z}[\varepsilon]\cap\Bbb{Q})
\cong(\Bbb{Z}[\varepsilon]\cdot\Bbb{Q})/\Bbb{Q},$$
But the left hand side is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$ whereas the right hand side is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}$. Where is my misunderstanding?

**EDIT:** The [second isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Second_isomorphism_theorem) states that for a group $G$, a subgroup $S$ and a normal subgroup $N\subset G$ there is a canonical isomorphism
$$S/(S\cap N)\cong(SN)/N,$$
where $SN$ is the subgroup of $G$ generated by $S$ and $N$.

Comment: Why the down vote ?

Comment: Hint : Be careful with the notation and the group structure. $\mathbb{Z}[\varepsilon].\mathbb{Q}$ is probably not what you think.

Comment: I do not know what is second isomorphism theorem. Can you add that in question.

Comment: @Roland I convinced myself that $\Bbb{Z}[\varepsilon]\cdot\Bbb{Q}=\Bbb{Q}[\varepsilon]$, but I see now that it is $\Bbb{Z}[\varepsilon]+\Bbb{Q}=\Bbb{Q}+\varepsilon\Bbb{Z}$. That solves my problem, thank you!

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Second_isomorphism_theorem

Comment: But here, the group operation is $+$, so $SN$ is really $S + N = \mathbb Z[\varepsilon] + \mathbb Q$.